# TS: Return type of function wrongly typed

Tags: typescript

I have the following types

```ts
export interface BackupItems {
  Playlist: {
    playlistItemList?: string[];
  };
}

export type BackupItemPatch<T extends keyof BackupItems> = BackupItems[T];
```

An element of type `BackupItemPatch<'Playlist'>` is checked *correctly* (`BackupItemPatch<'Playlist'>` has no property `id`):

```ts
const playlistPatch: BackupItemPatch<'Playlist'> = {
  playlistItemList: [],
  id: '1',              // ~~~error~~~
};
```

with error

```ts
Type '{ playlistItemList: undefined[]; id: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ playlistItemList?: string[]; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type '{ playlistItemList?: string[]; }'.(2322)
```

while

```ts
const patchPlaylist: () => BackupItemPatch<'Playlist'> = () => {
  return {
    playlistItemList: [],
    id: '1',
  };
};
```

does not give any error, although return type of `patchPlaylist` is also of type `BackupItemPatch<'Playlist'>`.

Note that if I omit `playlistItemList` property I get an error:

```ts
Type '() => { id: string; }' is not assignable to type '() => { playlistItemList?: string[]; }'.
  Type '{ id: string; }' has no properties in common with type '{ playlistItemList?: string[]; }'.(2322)
```

Also if `playlistItemList` is of wrong type (say an array of numbers):

```ts
Type '() => { playlistItemList: number[]; id: string; }' is not assignable to type '() => { playlistItemList?: string[]; }'.
  Call signature return types '{ playlistItemList: number[]; id: string; }' and '{ playlistItemList?: string[]; }' are incompatible.
    The types of 'playlistItemList' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
        Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
```

But why can I add properties that don't exist on `BackupItem<'Playlist'>`?
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-9cahui?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 0):

because when you declare the type of the function returning or receiving the typescript will only compare if the result is actually the parent of the type, i.e. the returned result must have at least the values ​​of the type

but when you declare `const playlistPatch:`  it will compare absolute `deep equal`